# why RestTemplate cannot be auto-wired without specifying the bean creation configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I did not find reason as to why spring provided this approach. is it because, we can configure rest template as per application requirement, like setting up timeout...etc. then give it to spring? if not why ?

Comment: What approach? There is a `RestTemplateBuilder` you can use so you can, if needed, tweak the settings. It also contains some sensible defaults and ability to bind properties from the `application.properties`. So not sure which appraoch you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly justified in the documentation

> Since RestTemplate instances often need to be customized before being used, Spring Boot does not provide any single auto-configured RestTemplate bean. It does, however, auto-configure a RestTemplateBuilder which can be used to create RestTemplate instances when needed